# assigning a numpy array based on list of tuples

Tags: python-2.7, list, numpy, indexing, tuples

I got a list of tuples, `idx = [ (1,4,), (2,3,), (0,), (0,3,4,) ]`;

I want to assign the indexes corresponding to the above list to 1.

First tuple `(1,4,)` contains the column indices corresponding to the first row, and second tuple `(2,3,)` contains the column indices corresponding to the second row etc. If `A = zeoros((8,5)` then `A[0,:]` should have 1 at column one and four.
`A[1,:]` should have 1 at column two and three. `A[2,:]` should have 1 at
column 0 etc

```
A = np.zeros((8,5))
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
idx = [ (1,4,), (2,3,), (0,), (0,3,4,) ];
```

after assigning according to the list of tuples, we get

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

How it can be done ?

Comment: Could you post an example along with the desired outcome?

Comment: @Cleb, i modified the question.

Comment: I don't understand the rules for assignment.

Comment: @Tai, it is based on the list of tuples.  First tuple contains the columns corresponding to the first row, and second tuple contains the column corresponding to the second row etc.

Comment: @Tai: The row number is implicit, the column number explicit. Though I don't see any skipped rows in the example. How would that be codified in the list of tuples?

Comment: @MrT thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
A = np.zeros((8,5))

idx = [ (1,4,), (2,3,), (0,), (0,3,4,) ]
idx_explicit = np.array(
    [[(i,j) for j in idx[i]] for i in range(len(idx))]).sum()
# [(0, 1), (0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (3, 0), (3, 3), (3, 4)]
A[tuple(np.transpose(idx_explicit))] = 1
```

See [`Integer array indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`scipy.sparse.coo_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html) like this:

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse
idx = [ (1,4,), (2,3,), (0,), (0,3,4,) ]
#create list with pair of row and column
idx_list = [(i, j) for i, tup in enumerate(idx) for j in tup]
#fill sparse matrix with 1 or any other data set and convert to array
arr = sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones(len(idx_list)), zip(*idx_list)), shape = (8, 5)).toarray()

#output
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```